# No pdf in Latex compilation even though the encoding is correct

Tags: compiling, texmaker, input-encodings, font-encodings

**EDIT 2**:
LINK TO DOWNLOAD THE `tex` FILE:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/a2aaczrqzobv1q2/send.zip

I have a .tex file whose preamble is this:

**EDIT:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\parindent 1 true cm
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage[british,spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib} 
\setcitestyle{square} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\pagestyle{fancy}                                     
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter .\ #1}{}}         
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection .\ #1}{}} 
\lhead{\nouppercase}
\rhead{\nouppercase}
\fancyhead[LE]{{\sf \leftmark}}                                 
\fancyhead[RE]{}                                                
\fancyhead[RO]{{\sf \rightmark}}                              
\fancyhead[LO]{} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}                                                         
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}                                
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{caption,setspace}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize,sf,stretch=0.80},labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\begin{document}
```

When I open this `.tex` file with Texmaker (program downloaded from: http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/texmaker_ubuntu_12.04_4.4.1_amd64.deb)

I reveive this error:

[image]

I click `OK` and the `.tex` file opens. Under `Options > Congigure Texmaker > Quick Build` I select the Latex option:

[image]

I compile and I receive this error:

[image]

I successfully compile this exact `.tex` file when I make: `bash make_latex.sh`. This `make_latex.sh` file makes the same as that Texmaker option:

```
#!/bin/bash
\rm *.blg *.bbl *.dvi *.aux *.log
latex dd
bibtex dd
latex dd
latex dd
dvips dd.dvi
ps2pdf dd.ps
evince dd.pdf
```

I would like to compile using Texmaker. I would appreciate if you could tell me how could I solve this problem.

**How could I successfully generate the pdf file?**

Comment: TexMakes should be able to show your the messages generated by Latex+Bibtex+... somewhere, even if the "file not found" error box pops up. Can you check if in the messages, you find any errors?

Comment: Well, what's in your document? I can typeset a very basic pdf using your preamble. So the "problem" needs to be identified in your code.

Comment: @Alenanno I have a Master Thesis. After making `Options > Congigure Texmaker > Quick Build`, with that Latex option (upper image), `dd.aux`,  `dd.toc`,  `dd.log`,  `dd.dvi`,  `dd.blg`, and `dd.bbl` files are generated. No  `dd.ps` nor `dd.pdf` files are generated, which means that `ps2pdf dd.ps`  does not work. If in terminal I make: `ps2pdf dd.ps`, then the `dd.pdf` file is generated.  Why `dd.ps` file is not generated?

Comment: From your list of generated files it looks like dvips is failing.  I can't see how that relates to whether the .tex file is utf-8 or not, because LaTeX successfully compiles to .dvi.  By the way, why are you compiling this way rather than pdflatex? .ps images?

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, I have `.ps` images

Comment: @ChrisH @Alenanno @DCTLib In the following link you can download the `tex` file in order to prove the compilation. Link also in **EDIT 2**:  http://www.mediafire.com/download/a2aaczrqzobv1q2/send.zip Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisH @Alenanno  The `NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers` IS not a problem, just press `enter` when making `bash make_latex.sh` or ignore the message in Texmaker. Remember the central problem: `pdf` is generated by `bash make_latex.sh` but no by Texmaker

Comment: OK so it compiles here using the script.  I don't have texmaker installed to test -- I used jEdit, some scripts, and terminal commands when I wrote my thesis.  I'm tempted to suggest that you just compile from the terminal, but what I will suggest is that you fix the error before digging too deep in this compilation issue as you have a workaround -- I know you can skip it but skipping errors to get the file to compile (i) makes diagnosis harder, and (ii) can mask your real problem.  Similarly I'd fix the errors reported by bibtex...

Comment: ..When I found errors I always found it helpful to compile step-by-step from the terminal.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, with great respect, but _you have already described what I have posted above ..._ the main problem is _still_ unresolved.... I _do_ need to use Texmaker...